# In Gradle 8 (build tool) kts DSL, how to split sections that depends on KotlinBuildScript and plugins in a `build.gradle.kts` file into another file?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Assuming that several Gradle projects are sharing the same plugin & buildScript settings:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // Add here whatever repositories you're already using
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("ch.epfl.scala:gradle-bloop_2.12:1.4.13") // suffix is always 2.12, weird
    }
}

plugins {
//    base
    java
    `java-test-fixtures`

    scala
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.10" // TODO: remove?

    idea

    `maven-publish`
}
```

Both sections are declared under `KotlinBuildScript`:

```
@Deprecated("Will be removed in Gradle 9.0")
abstract class KotlinBuildScript(
    private val host: KotlinScriptHost<Project>
) : @Suppress("DEPRECATION") org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.support.delegates.ProjectDelegate() {
...
```

I would like to move them into a shared git submodule, a few online articles suggested that I should exploit the KotlinScript class extension feature and aggregate them into an extension like this, either under `buildSrc` directory (automatically included in KotlinScript interpretation classpath) or under the same `build.gradle.kts` script. All these articles use `Project` class as an example:

```
fun Project.xxx(): Versions {
}
```

But when I try to apply this solution to `KotlinBuildScript`, I got the following error:

```
// under build.gradle.kts
fun KotlinBuildScript.dummy(): Unit {}

dummy()
```

error:

```
build.gradle.kts:6:1: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public final fun KotlinBuildScript.dummy(): Unit defined in Build_gradle
```

What's the cause of this error? If `KotlinBuildScript` is not the receiver (which still doesn't explain why `buildscript` & `plugins` are in script root scope), what should be used instead?

**UPDATE 1**: It appears that extensions to `Project` class only works under 1 condition: they have to be defined under `build.gradle.kts`, once moved into `buildSrc`, any invocation of Gradle plugin will cause a compilation error:

```
//under `buildSrc/.../init.kt`

fun Project.dummy2(): Unit {

    idea {
    }
}
```

this will cause the error:

```
e: file:///home/peng/git-proto/scaffold-gradle-kts/buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/init.kt:17:5 Expression 'idea' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found
e: file:///home/peng/git-proto/scaffold-gradle-kts/buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/init.kt:17:5 Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public val PluginDependenciesSpec.idea: PluginDependencySpec defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

So both extension fail, what should be done in these cases?

The described experiment and errors can be observed in the following project:

https://github.com/tribbloid/scaffold-gradle-kts/blob/cdb18cd40fa862aaf4cfea1af2f75165a186bd89/buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/init.kt